# BeautifulSoup - find_all div tags with different class name

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to select all `<div>` where class name is either `post has-profile bg2` OR `post has-profile bg1` but not last one i.e. `panel`

```
<div id="6" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 1 </div>
<div id="7" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 2 </div>
<div id="8" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 3 </div>
<div id="9" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 4 </div>

<div class="panel bg1" id="abc"> ... </div>
```

`select()` is matching only single occurrence. I'm trying it with `find_all()`, but bs4 is not able to find it.

```
if soup.find(class_ = re.compile(r"post has-profile [bg1|bg2]")):
    posts = soup.find_all(class_ = re.compile(r"post has-profile [bg1|bg2]"))
```

How to solve it with regex and without regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use builtin CSS selector within BeautifulSoup:

```
data = """<div id="6" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 1 </div>
<div id="7" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 2 </div>
<div id="8" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 3 </div>
<div id="9" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 4 </div>
<div class="panel bg1" id="abc"> ... </div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

divs = soup.select('div.post.has-profile.bg2, div.post.has-profile.bg1')

for div in divs:
    print(div)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
<div class="post has-profile bg2" id="6"> some text 1 </div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="post has-profile bg2" id="8"> some text 3 </div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="post has-profile bg1" id="7"> some text 2 </div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="post has-profile bg1" id="9"> some text 4 </div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `'div.post.has-profile.bg2, div.post.has-profile.bg1'` selector selects all `<div>` tags with class `"post hast-profile bg2"` and all `<div>` tags with class `"post hast-profile bg1"`.

Comment: That's a perfect answer in a beautifulSoup way. I didn't know that select() can accept multiple arguments like this.

Comment: @pss your regex seems ok, I would try to remove square brackets and put parenthesis - `(bg1|bg2)`. But depends what input you parse through BeautifulSoup. Your regex will match all divs only if they have their class in specified order.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that describes the tags of interest:

```
def test_tag(tag):
    return tag.name=='div' \
       and tag.has_attr('class') \
       and "post" in tag['class'] \
       and "has-profile" in tag['class'] \
       and ("bg1" in tag['class'] or "bg2" in tag['class']) \
       and "panel" not in tag['class']
```

And apply the function to the "soup":

```
soup.findAll(test_tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Try:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = """<div id="6" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 1 </div>
<div id="7" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 2 </div>
<div id="8" class="post has-profile bg2"> some text 3 </div>
<div id="9" class="post has-profile bg1"> some text 4 </div>

<div class="panel bg1" id="abc"> ... </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all("div", class_=re.compile(r"post has-profile bg(1|2)")):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="post has-profile bg2" id="6"> some text 1 </div>
<div class="post has-profile bg1" id="7"> some text 2 </div>
<div class="post has-profile bg2" id="8"> some text 3 </div>
<div class="post has-profile bg1" id="9"> some text 4 </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code as it is but there is nothing in output i.e blank output.

Comment: How are you getting the raw html? using `requests.get`?

Comment: Raw html is in database. I am assigning raw html to a variable - `content = mydocDict['content']`  `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')`