# Select all divs except ones with certain classes in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, beautifulsoup

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588952/beautifulsoup-find-all-div-tags-with-different-class-name) one can easily get all `div`s with certain classes. But here, I have a list of classes that I want to exclude & want to get all divs that doesn't have any class given in the list.

For i.e.

```
classToIgnore = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
```

Now want to get all divs that doesn't contains the classes mentioned above list. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate solution

```
soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x not in classToIgnore)
```

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c4"></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
classToIgnore = ["c1", "c2"]
print(soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x not in classToIgnore))
```

Output

```
[<div class="c3"></div>, <div class="c4"></div>]
```

If you are dealing with nested classes then try deleting the inner unwanted classes using *[decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose)* and then just `find_all('div')`

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x in classToIgnore):
    div.decompose()
print(soup.find_all('div'))
```

This might leave some extra spaces but you can strip that off easily later.

Comment: It looks like it should work but it was not excluding any of the classes.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi I am not sure why. I have included a working example.

Comment: i guess the issue is in my case, sometimes `div` with class `c1` and `c2` are part of `div` with class `c3` or `c4`. Means in nested divs, the excluded ones will still come as part of included ones.

Comment: simple & elegant. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS selector, try this:

```
divs = soup.select("div:not('.class1, .class2, .class3')")
```

#### Reference

1. [Link 1](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)
2. [Link 2](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although i need to make all the classes into separate single commas like `('.class1', '.class2', '.class3')` to make it work. Also, is it mandatory for `class` to be a first attribute in `div`?

Comment: No, attributes can be in any place with in the tag, their order should not have any impact at all.