# Select divs according to various parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and trying to **scrape** a particular website with certain parameters. Now, I want to fetch divs that satisfies following conditions:

1. I want to exclude `div` which has certain `class` in it.
2. I want to exclude `div` which doesn't have `class` attribute.
3. I want to include `div` that have a particular `id` and either doesn't have any class or does have class other than ignored class list.

Now, i have accomplished 2 conditions so far with following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310935/select-all-divs-except-ones-with-certain-classes-in-beautifulsoup):

```
classToIgnore = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x in classToIgnore):
    div.decompose()

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_=False):   
    div.decompose()
```

Now, I don't know how to add 3rd condition here & also want to do all 3 filters within single `find_all()` statement, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with such complicated conditions, it is always a best practice to wrap it in a separate function. BeautifulSoup allows you to use a [function as filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
html = """
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c1" id="myid">
    <div class="c1"></div>
</div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3" id="myid"></div>
<div class="c4"></div>
<div></div>
<div id="myid"></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
classToIgnore = ["c1", "c2"]

# Using decompose to solve cases where
# unwanted classes comes inside wanted classes
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x in classToIgnore):
    div.decompose()


def my_filter(ele):
    if (
        isinstance(ele, Tag) and
        ele.name == 'div' and
        ele.get('id') == 'myid' and not ele.get('class') or
        ele.get('class')
    ):
        return True


print(soup.find_all(my_filter))
```

Output

```
[<div class="c3" id="myid"></div>, <div class="c4"></div>, <div id="myid"></div>]
```

Comment: i think you might misunderstood the question. `<div class="c4"></div>
<div id="myid"></div>` should also come in my output.

Comment: i had put the question wrong way. I've updated the question. Please check condition 3 again.

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed some cases so please try the following with bs4 4.7.1 + which uses :not for exclusions or css And syntax. Note I have altered your class names in the list to be selectors by preceeding with "."

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

classes_to_ignore = [".class1", ".class2", ".class3"]

html = '''
<div class="class1">a</div>
<div class="class2">b</div>
<div class="class3">c</div>
<div class="class4">d</div>
<div>e</div>
<div id="id1" class="class5">f</div>
<div id="id1">g</div>
<div id="id1" class="class1">h</div>
<div id="id1" class="class2">i</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
ignore = ','.join(classes_to_ignore)
divs = soup.select(f"div[id='id1']:not({ignore}), div:not({ignore})[class]")
print(divs)
```