# Ignore one div class in BeautifulSoup find_all in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to ignore one class when using find_all. I've followed this solution [Select all divs except ones with certain classes in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310935/select-all-divs-except-ones-with-certain-classes-in-beautifulsoup)

My divs are a bit different, I want to ignore description-0

```
<div class="abc">...</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="description-0"></div>
    <div class="description-1"></div>
    <div class="description-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="xyz">...</div>
```

Following is my code

```
classToIgnore = ["description-0"]
all = soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda x: x not in classToIgnore)
```

It is reading all divs on the page, instead of just the ones with "descriptions-n". How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex`, like this, for example:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """<div class="abc">...</div>
<div class="description-0"></div>
<div class="description-1"></div>
<div class="description-2"></div>
<div class="xyz">...</div>"""

classes_regex = (
    BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "lxml")
    .find_all("div", {"class": (re.compile(r"description-[1-9]"))})
)
print(classes_regex)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="description-1"></div>, <div class="description-2"></div>]
```

Comment: Sorry, you missed the main requirement. I want to ignore "description-0" and read all divs from description-1/2/3....

Comment: I've just updated the answer.